# sql/php/session update userprofile

Tags: php, sql, session, sql-update

I know there are already a lot of questions asked about this topic. But Sadly  my userprofile just does not wanna update when i type a different input and press on the update button. I need to finish this School exercise by wendsday and i really don't have somebody else then stack to ask. Hope you guys can help me out.
My Problem:
I will always get the output `update not successful` and it will never update any record in my database. And I am not sure what to do differently cause i realy tryed almost everything.

welcome.php:

```
<?php
 include("../php/session.php");
?>


<div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="imagepageback">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="profilimage"></div>
                                <hr class="verticalline">                   
                                    <form class="form" action="" method="post">
                                    <input id="username" class="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="email" class="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="firstname" class="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="lastname" class="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="birthdate" class="birthdate" type="text" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo $birthdate; ?>" readonly>
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="street" class="street" type="text" name="street" value="<?php echo $street; ?>" readonly>
                                        <input id="nr" class="nr" type="text" name="streetnr" value="<?php echo $streetnr; ?>" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="city" class="city" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" readonly>
                                        <input id="plzz" class="plzz" type="text" name="plzz" value="<?php echo $plzz; ?>" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="editprofilelink" id="editprofilelink"  onclick="editable(); showbt()"; >Edit Profile</a>
                                    <a href="changepd.html" class="editpasswordlink">Change Password</a>
                                        <!----------PHP Skript----------->
                                        <?php 
                                       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                                       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
                                       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
                                       $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['firstname']);
                                       $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['lastname']);
                                       $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['birthdate']);
                                       $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['street']);
                                       $streetnr = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['streetnr']);
                                       $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['city']);
                                       $plzz = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['plzz']);


                                      $sql = "UPDATE clients SET " .
                                            "email = '$email', " .
                                            "username = '$username', " .
                                            "firstname = '$firstname', " . 
                                            "lastname = '$lastname', " .
                                            "birthdate = '$birthdate', " .
                                            "street = '$street', " .
                                            "streetnr = '$streetnr', " .
                                            "city = '$city', " .
                                            "plzz = '$plzz' " .
                                            "WHERE username = '$username'";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

                                       if($result) {
                                         $_POST["email"] = $email;
                                         $_POST["username"] = $username;
                                         $_POST["firstname"] = $firstname;
                                         $_POST["lastname"] = $lastname;
                                         $_POST["birthdate"] = $birthdate;
                                         $_POST["street"] = $street;
                                         $_POST["streetnr"] = $streetnr;
                                         $_POST["city"] = $city;
                                         $_POST["plzz"] = $plzz;

                                         header("location:http://localhost:81/Left_over_youth_website/php/logout.php");
                                       }else {
                                         echo '<p id="error">Update was not sucessful</p>';
                                       }
                                       }
                                     ?>  
                                    <input hidden id="btupdate" type="submit" name="btupdate" value="Update">   
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    session_start();

    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:http://localhost:81/Left_over_youth_website/pages/login.php");
    }
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'leftoveryouth');  
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

database:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetnr` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plzz` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is db fieldname for "nrr = '$streetnr'" - Is it nrr?? And for plzz- you are not using any parameters in update query, where as you are passing value : $_SESSION["plzz"] = $plz

Comment: check my update. plzz is =plzz also in the database nrr = streetnr in database. I am pretty sure my problem has nothing to do with the naming

Comment: Look at your query; `birthdatee = '$birthdate'` you do not have a database field called `birthdatee` it's `birthdate`

Comment: In your SQL string, remove all `and` with comma `,`

Comment: You should look into using [MySQLi prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) aswell..

Comment: Hey I am seeing two mistakes one is when your are posting data from a form It's received in POST global array not session so $name=POST['name'].and updating takes a where clause you need to tell it which row to update

Comment: @Hazaki but I can see some issues with column names, UPDATE clients SET emaill - double l in email

Comment: @IsThisJavascript birthdatee(input field Name)=$birthdate(is:$birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_SESSION['birthdate']);)

Comment: Actually looking at your query more there's even more mistakes. Please double check your table names and remove the excess letters from them... I'm looking at : `emaill` `usernamee`  `firstnamee` `lastnamee` and `birthdatee` and I cannot see a `nrr`

Comment: In your SQL string, you need to add a WHERE clause for the particular client record you want to update, otherwise, the query you have will overwrite all records in database.

Comment: There's so many obvious errors here; http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ & http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Hazaki what do you even mean with that comment? I see from your create table schema; `\`birthdate\` date DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: @Mowzey so I have to $Name=$Post['name'] instead of $Name=$_SESSION got it. I am not sure how to do that cause with session i would not Need that cause it always should only update the data of the current user. I am not sure how to do that with post

Comment: Your sessions don't get set because of your massive SQL issues. Address them like others have said.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript yes $birthdate is = birthdate in db and birthdatee should give me input field value

Comment: No sir, it doesn't, your database column name is `birthdate` and you're trying to update a column called `birthdatee`. Your SQL fails because it cannot find any of those columns

Comment: @IsThisJavascript alright so can you tell me how i can select the current input field value and update... how do i Need to write my $SQL= ... i am so confused right now

Comment: @Hazaki I can tell you are confused, it's a simple fix but I want to see if Mowzey can fix it. Stay tuned on his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several variable name errors in the code. For example, one `input` is named `streett` but when reading from `$_SESSION[]` it's trying to be read as `street`.

`$_SESSION[]` can't read POST data. You need to use `$_POST[]` instead.

Column names in the SQL query are wrong according to the CREATE statement you provided. Also, in the final part of the query, you didn't include a `$` for the variable `$plzz` which was also spelled wrong according to your code.

Always check your variables for spelling and case errors when things don't work right.

Also, in SQL, the proper format for doing an update is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

As mentioned by @Karlo in the comments, remove the `and` keyword and comma delimit the updates you are doing.

Finally, you must use a `WHERE` statement to limit which rows are being updated. Otherwise, you will be updating all rows in the database.

Old Query: (I created multiple lines so changes can been seen easier)

```php
$sql = "UPDATE clients SET " .
    "emaill = '$email' and " .
    "usernamee = '$username' and " .
    "firstnamee = '$firstname' and " .
    "lastnamee = '$lastname' and " .
    "birthdatee = '$birthdate' and " .
    "street = '$street' and " .
    "nrr = '$streetnr' and " .
    "city = '$city' and " .
    "plzz = 'plz'";
```

New Query based on columns provided:

```
$sql = "UPDATE clients SET " .
    "email = '$email', " .
    "username = '$username', " .
    "firstname = '$firstname', " . 
    "lastname = '$lastname', " .
    "birthdate = '$birthdate', " .
    "street = '$street', " .
    "streetnr = '$streetnr', " .
    "city = '$city', " .
    "plzz = '$plzz' " .
    "WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented everything you said. I have update the code to my question. Could you take another look at it. It still doesen't work. And how can i show the data of for example the email input field...logically (echo $_SESSION['email'] )doesen't work anymore

Comment: In your `if($result) { ... }` area you would set your `$_SESSION[]` variables. So, change those back.

Comment: As I stated in the answer, you cannot read POST information from `$_SESSION[]`. But, as you were trying to do, taking the POST info and creating session variables from it was correct.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm no genius. I've just been down the same road as you many years ago. Just sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, Aces your form data using post global array like

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Then sql

```
    $sql = "UPDATE profile SET name = '".$name.'" WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid].'"; 
    $update = $connection->query($sql);
    if($update){
        $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    }
```

This is if your updating current information of the logged in person, am assuming your keep their id or something to uniquely identify them

Comment: I really hate downvoting (I don't really I actually love it), but you need far more information in this post to solve the OPs issues. If you're going to provide a solution, include the full SQL code to fix it aswell as addressing the other issues.

Comment: @Mowzey  no i diden't do that with the id. When the user is logged in $_SESSION holds the information about the user

Comment: @Hazaki then use a field that is unique about your user in the database it could be email address, what do you keep in session on login?

Comment: @Mowzey how can i store the userid in the session?

Comment: On login, query the db for userid or email and do $_SESSION['userid']=$id;